# apt-cacher-ng doesn't responce after start

Tags: debian, centos, strace

**Problem**

`apt-get` command (on Debian) cannot access repos via `apt-cacher-ng` proxy (installed on Centos).

**Environment**

```
# /etc/centos-release
CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804 (Core)

$ yum -q info apt-cacher-ng.x86_64
Installed Packages
Name        : apt-cacher-ng
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 3.1
Release     : 4.el7
...
From repo   : epel
...
```

Debians are 7.11

**Details**

`tcpdump` on Centos shows that there are no any answer from `apt-cacher-ng` to (single) `apt-get`'s request:

```
# tcpdump -i eno1 -nn port 3142                                                                                                                                                                
...
15:05:17.528378 IP 10.XX.XX.XX.38562 > 10.YY.YY.YY.3142: Flags [S], seq 2752129391, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 85570664 ecr 0,nop,wscale 4], length 0
```

`strace` on Centows shows that `apt-cacher-ng` hangs on `select()` system call:

```
...
open("/dev/null", O_RDWR)               = 6
fstat(6, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0666, st_rdev=makedev(1, 3), ...}) = 0
dup2(6, 0)                              = 0
dup2(6, 1)                              = 1
dup2(6, 2)                              = 2
close(6)                                = 0
select(6, [5], [], NULL, NULL
```

Full trace on Paste: https://paste.ee/p/lLtS8#s=0

There is no reaction in strace to incoming packets on listening 3142 port.

**Edit**

There is single string in logfile:

```
Tue Oct  2 14:18:15 2018|Not creating Unix Domain Socket, fifo_path not specified
```

But I don't know when it appeared (launches were much more than one).

**Edit2**

Clients are configured with `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/00aptproxy` file:

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://10.XX.XX.XX:3142";
```

SELinux is in permissive mode.

Firewall has a rule:

```
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 3142 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
```

**Edit3**

Current acng's config:

```
# grep -Ev "^$|^#" /etc/apt-cacher-ng/acng.conf 
CacheDir: /var/cache/apt-cacher-ng
LogDir: /var/log/apt-cacher-ng
SupportDir: @LIBDIR@
Port:3142
BindAddress:0.0.0.0
ReportPage: acng-report.html
VerboseLog: 1
ForeGround: 1
ExThreshold: 4
Debug: 7
LocalDirs: acng-doc @DOCDIR@
UseWrap: 0
```

Sic(!) Internal WebUI is available with `curl 127.0.0.1:3142`, but not from clients (`curl 10.XX.XX.XX:3142`)

**Edit4**

```
# cat /sys/class/net/eno1/statistics/rx_dropped
0
```

`dropwatch -l kas` does't show any drops, too (when I run `apt-cacher-ng` and `apt-get update` on client).

How to trace TCP/IP stack right? Google says this 2 methods are enough.. (`ifconfig` and `netstat` are not available in repos and `ethtool` doesn't support `-S` flag)

---

Just now I have no idea where to dig next to solve this problem.

I don't understand if monitoring of `fd6` (`/dev/null`) is the real problem and why process need to clone this fd..

Сan anyone suggest what else I can check to find the root cause or prompt workaround?

Comment: Have you configured APT on the client machines to have apt-cacher-ng as proxy?

Comment: @rui-f-ribeiro, yes, clients are configured:

Comment: to debug/strace daemons, you have to usually use the debug option and run them in the foreground, or otherwise they will fork in the process of daemonization

Comment: is se linux activated? try to switch it off to see if this goes away.

Comment: @rui-f-ribeiro, seems that there is no suitable option for background/foreground and verbose/debugging modes

Comment: SELinux is in permissive mode

Comment: For debugging in foreground `apt-cacher-ng ForeGround=1`

Comment: # /usr/sbin/apt-cacher-ng ForeGround=1 VerboseLog=1 Debug=7 -c /etc/apt-cacher-ng/    
Warning: configured to use libwrap filters but feature is not built-in.
# nothing here when run apt-get...

Comment: I disabled libwrap (UseWrap: 0) - nothig changed..

Comment: It would be interesting to have a look at strace then in debug mode with libwrap disabled.

Comment: https://paste.ee/p/JaX9J

I guess acng process really doesn't retrieve any ip-packets..

Comment: There is something that is not being created there. A socket? A file? ... I used apt-cacher-ng in Debian for many years and never had much problems. I cannot guarantee whether or not it is so much a good idea trying to use it elsewhere.